# How does accessibilityTextContentType changes Texts in SwiftUI using VoiceOver

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

The `Text` in Swift has the [`accessibilityTextContentType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/accessibilitytextcontenttype(_:))  instance method. I can't seem to figure out or notice what it changes if I'm using my app with VoiceOver.

The documentation says:

> Assistive technologies can use this property to choose an appropriate way to output the text. For example, when encountering a source coding context, VoiceOver could choose to speak all punctuation.

That's a lot of *could*s and *can*s... Unfortunately, I could not come up with any text that resulted in different output in VoiceOver with different accessibility text content types.

For example, I tried these below, and many others, expecting a change:

```
Text("/home/user/documents/photos/2024/vacation/destination/").accessibilityTextContentType(.fileSystem)
Text("/home/user/documents/photos/2024/vacation/destination/").accessibilityTextContentType(.plain)

Text("void main(List<String> arguments) { print('Hello $args'); }").accessibilityTextContentType(.sourceCode)
Text("void main(List<String> arguments) { print('Hello $args'); }").accessibilityTextContentType(.plain)
```

I'd like to better understand how the accessibility content type changes the output of the text in assistive technologies, but so far, I could not even come up with a single example that resulted in a different output.

If you could enlighten me with some examples, or maybe point out what I'm doing wrong, that would be appreciated.

Comment: From what I have read and understood, it seems that you can only mark it, but the framework will decide on their own. If you actually want it to read punctuation, you could use [speechAlwaysIncludesPunctuation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/speechalwaysincludespunctuation(_:))